# Apache .htaccess: Redirect to an URL containing a hashtag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, escaping, hashtag

The URLs

> https://example.com/moved/
>
> https://www.example.com/moved/

should be redirected to the URL

> https://my.example.com/#views/settings.php?id=2

**via .htaccess**.

This is what I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} moved$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://my.example.com/#views/settings.php?id=2 [R=301,L]
```

However it seems not to work. I guess the reason is the #hashtag within the URL where I want to redirect to (it marks a comment within .htaccess).

How to redirect this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^moved/?$ https://my.example.com/#views/settings.php?id=2 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

- `^(?:www\.)?example\.com$` will match `www.example.com` and `example.com`
- Flag `NE` is used for **no escaping** of `#` in redirected URL
- Pattern `moved/?$` matches `/moved/` and `/moved`, thus making trailing slash optional.

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.

Comment: Looks great thanks! I can not test right now but I think there is nothing more to add.